# Why google analytics do not collect conversions?

Tags: post, google-analytics

I am making POST request to this endpoint `www.google-analytics.com/collect` with following data:

```
v=1&tid=UA-XXX&cid=123&t=pageview&ti=123&tr=21&pa=purchase&pr1id=123&pr1nm=pu&dp=thankyoupage
```

Why I can't see this conversion on Google Analytics Real-Time Conversion dashboard?

Comment: I just sent your hit to my account I can see it on the real time api.

Comment: in conversions or events tab?

Comment: you are sending t=pageview not t=event, i wouldn't expect to see it under event.

Comment: so in which tab I can see it? I need to send conversion purchase with value.

Comment: Show your goal configuration, pls

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a goal in GA View settings with your `destination` path. Here an example, in your case you have to set Destination as `thankyoupage`.

[image]

Comment: It was enabled, I have disabled it, but still I can't see conversions in Conversion tab and in Content Tab(Pageview)

Comment: I updated my answer based on your private message.

Comment: the event/conversion is sent from the backend, after user purchase some product. But this event/conversion can be sent 5 minutes after the real purchase due to asynchronous command. So how should I set it?

Comment: Your hit is not an event, it is a pageview. For this reason you have to choose Destination and not Event in Goal settings.

Comment: I want to have a conversion(purchase), which is sent from the backend. What should I do?

Comment: What I wrote before, if thankyoupage is purchase page you have to set that as destination to get +1 convertion in Analytics.

Comment: But I do not have a thank-you page. I am sending a hit from the backend, where the purchase is being made.

Comment: You defined &dp=thankyoupage in your hit... anyway I thank you're confusing real-time conversions and transactions.